# Target/Change Divi Slider in Wordpress with a Link

Tags: wordpress, slider, themes

I am using the Divi theme from Elegant Themes on WP trying to change the slide showing within the slider by using a text link. I still want the dot navigation to show below the text but primarily want to navigate the slider by using text buttons above: The link is here: http://raygunworkshop.com/project/edwin-the-duck/

Scroll to see where you see POSITIONING STATEMENT, CHAMPION STATEMENT,
VALUE PROPOSITION etc on the blue background. The look is setup how I want - I just cannot seem to figure out the function. Needs to work on mobile as well.

Is there a way to do this? Theme support could not assist.